# Explain SQL Query execution in this case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am using a sql query i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

In this Table_Name table has 10 rows and 5 columns. When I run this above query it runs fine and return 10 rows and 5 columns.

Now I am running a new query i.e.

```
SELECT 8 FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Now it will return only a single column but 10 rows and this single column has same values i.e. 8 in each row.

I want to know that why it return me 10 rows and a column which has only 8 value and when i am using * instead of 8 in that case it will return 10 rows and 5 columns.

What exactly the difference between both queries and its execution process?

Answer (score 2):

You select the columns after `SELECT` like `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table`.
If you type `8` you "just get a constant 8".

If you want just 8 rows, in sql server you specify it with `SELECT TOP 8 col1, col2 FROM table`.

If you want to learn more about sql in general here is a good start: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Answer (score 1):

if you define no `where` clause then all rows will be fetched.

If you define `8` instead of `*` then the number `8` will be return in each row. `*` is a wildcard for all column names and is like doing `SELECT col1, col2, ..., col10 FROM TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT 8` is just selecting a constant. It returns that value for every row in the table. It's just like saying:

```
SELECT 8, some_other_column FROM dbo.table_name;
```

In that case you get a column holding `8` in every row, but you get another column too. If you don't specify any other columns, SQL Server scans the table and fetches your constant for every row, but no other data.

Answer (score 1):

After the `SELECT` you specify the columns you want to have returned.

`*` here is a simple placeholder for "give me all there is", so all columns present are returned.

If you pass a mere constant, in your case an `8`, in the column list, it will return just that constant for every row, resulting in ten rows with one column, whose content is `8`.

You might also combine those two like

```
SELECT *, 8 FROM TABLE_NAME
```

In your case this would return you 6 columns - 5 from your original table and one constant column.

Answer (score 1):

The **[SELECT clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)** specifies the columns to be returned. * tells the server to return all the columns that are available for each record in the table. 8 means to return the value 8 for each record in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The SELECT clause is like a loop that goes through all the rows in the FROM clause, subject to the JOINs and GROUP BYs.

In your simple query, the first version is saying "return all values in the rows for each row in the table."

The second version is saying "return the value 8 for each row in the table".

This is how SQL works, and is not a function of the particular engine.

Answer (score 1):

All answers are has very good approach, sql is well programmed for `select *` syntax.
and when we write `select 8` it tries to find the need of the developer. just based on the table, conditions we are applying.. `select 8` will behave same like `*` in terms of number of rows like just choose some random `where` conditions and apply on both `8 and` * number of rows will be same but number of column in case of `*` will be exact the table has and in case of `8` it will be just one as `8` is not a reserved literal of sql, it takes `8` as a hard coded column name and whose value will be defined by programmer either hard coded or by some formulation.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should consider that you are doing a query to the table `TABLE_NAME`, this table should have 10 rows, now when you do the query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

You're saying that it must bring all the rows from the table and **show all columns**, but if you do this

```
SELECT 8 FROM TABLE_NAME
```

You're saying that it must bring all the rows from the table but **instead of showing a column for the table it will show an 8**, and it will do it 10 times, because the table has 10 rows; you can execute this query

```
SELECT 8
```

And it will only show one row with an 8 value because you're not doing a query to a table, if you do a query to X table with this it will show you as N rows as N lines has the table but only with 8.